# How to fix TypeError

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried to run this script and keep getting the following error.  can someone help and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 6, file "")

here is the script I'm trying to run

```
function add() {

var sheetName = "Purchase Order Form" ;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PurchaseOrderForm");
var range = ss.getRange("A1");
var value = range.getValue("A1");

range.setValue(value + 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, there are two different sheet names given: first one is declared here *(Purchase Order Form)*:

```
var sheetName = "Purchase Order Form" ;
```

whereas later in the code, you select a sheet with different name *(PurchaseOrderForm)*:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PurchaseOrderForm");
```

You have to ensure that you input the correct name of the sheet. Also, you do not need to input the cell coordinates for getValue(), as in

```
range.getValue("A1");
```

If you'd like to retain the sheet name in the variable, here's the corrected & tested code for sheet named *Purchase Order Form*:

```
function add() {
  var sheetName = "Purchase Order Form";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = ss.getRange("A1"); 
  var value = range.getValue();
  range.setValue(value + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, I appreciate the feedback.  I impimented this and it is working.  beings i'mm a new to this I have two functions in one code but when the script is called upon which in my instance is from a link from a website it is only running the one function.  is there a way to be able to run my first function and then follow it up witht the second one?

Comment: here is the code. sorry pushed enter to quickfunction sitesLink() {
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1xNGp16Wxc_3X26_bOIXV521_km3YCLuzphkapvmka1A');
 GmailApp.sendEmail('chris_smith@lumixelectrical.com', 'Purchase Order Form', 'Please see the attached file.', {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 })}

function add() {
var sheetName = "Purchase Order Form" ;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
var range = ss.getRange("A1");
var value = range.getValue();

range.setValue(value + 1);

}

Comment: If my solution worked, please, markit the aswer as correct. If you have any further questions, it would be better not to state them in comments: that causes problems with text formatting and so on.

As for the script: you can copy all the code from between **{ }** of one script and paste it in between the **{ }** of the other script (in proper order, as far as the execution is concerned). That should work, but since I do not know any details on the file, I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: Thanks for all your input.  I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to select the sheet within the spreadsheet (a spreadsheet can have multiple sheets).

```
function add() {

var sheetName = "Purchase Order Form" ;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PurchaseOrderForm");

// select the first sheet.
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("A1"); 
var value = range.getValue("A1");

range.setValue(value + 1);

}
```